# How to model a consecutive binary constraint?

Tags: integer-programming, constraints

Let us say we have $n$ binary variables $x_i$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, i.e., $x_i\in\{0,1\}$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

I need to write the following constraint:

- If $x_i=1$ and $x_{i+2}=1$, then $x_{i+1}=1$. In other words, the variables $x_i$ must be consecutives.

I tried with this one:

$$x_i+x_{i+2}\leqslant 2x_{i+1},\tag{1}$$

which does not quite translate what I need. In fact, inequality $(1)$ says that: if $x_i=1$ and $x_{i+2}=1$, then $x_{i+1}=1$. **But**  it also says that: if, for example, $x_i=1$ and $x_{i+2}=0$, then $x_{i+1}=1$, which does not have to be true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To model the implication as described in the question
$$
  x_i=1 \text{ and } x_{i+2}=1 \Rightarrow x_{i+1} = 1
$$
add the constraints:
$$
x_i -x_{i+1} + x_{i+2} \le 1
$$
(no extra variables needed with this formulation)

#### Different interpretation of the question

Suppose you want all $x_i =1$ to be contiguous (i.e, no holes). A standard formulation for this is to limit the number of "start-ups" to one:
$$
\begin{align}
   &s_i \ge x_i-x_{i-1}\\
   &\sum_i s_i \le 1\\
   &s_i \in \{0,1\} 
\end{align}
$$
A "start-up" occurs when we switch from $0$ to $1$, in which case we force $s_i=1$. Note that $s_i$ can be relaxed to be continuous between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: It seems that Zir wanted to ensure all variables to be consecutive. This constraint does not prevent e.g. 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0. More constraints are needed.

Comment: @Ben I don't see that in the question, but that is a fairly standard modeling problem.

Comment: Does $s_i$ become a decision variable in this format?

Comment: Yes, $s_i$ depends on $x_i$, so it is a (binary) variable.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, do you know a paper with an example of consecutive scheduling you could reference? (If you dont mind)

Comment: @DJK I don't have a reference readily available. These type of restricting the number of start-ups is often encountered in modeling power generators.  Basically this is to reduce wear and tear on the equipment. You should be able to find this type of formulations in unit-commitment models. Here is a [link](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2014/12/modeling-number-of-machine-start-ups.html).

Answer (score 2):

Add $2n-2$ extra variables $t_i = x_{i+1}-x_i$ and $s_i = -x_i-x_{i+1}$.

Then
$$\sum_1^{n-1} t_i + \sum_1^{n-1} s_i \leq 2 
$$